# Integral, Fourier Series

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-series

Given that: $$f(t)= \begin{cases} -1& \text{if } t<0 \\2 &\text{if } t\geq0 \end{cases}$$ and assuming that ${{\omega }_{0}}=$$\frac{2\pi}{T}$

How do I calculate the following integral?
\begin{equation}
a_0=\frac{2}{T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}f(t)\cos(2{{\omega }_{0}}t)~dt
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

Integrate from $-T/2$ to $0$ and from $0$ to $T/2$